# Is this mathlish ambiguous? “For all subsets $C, D \subseteq A$ , …”

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wrote a math practice question as

> For all subsets  $C, D \subseteq A$, is it true that....

What I meant was ***both*** C and D are the subsets of A.

However, a student said what he understood is the "all subsets", being a quantifier, was to describe the properties of C and D. This implied "C and D are the all subsets A has", which is "C and D are the only subsets belong to A".

I have never thought someone would understand in this way. So out of curiosity, is my statement ambiguous?

I originally post this question in English and Language Usage, but a person said it is more like "Mathlish" problem. So I think I can get some help here.

Comment: What you wrote is fine. Yes, the "for all" _is_ a quantifier. That doesn't mean that what you wrote means what the student thought. That's ridiculous - "for every $x\in\Bbb R$ we have $x^2\ge0$" does not say that $\Bbb R$ has only one element.

Comment: Most obviously, your statement is clear. A student of mine thought that "Does it have solutions?" meant "Does it have at least two solutions?", as if "Do you have sons?" could mean "Do you have at least two sons?". But you can't win them all, so you can always rephrase it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some sence it is ambiguous, just like any statement. There are possible multiple ways to interpret words. This interpretation provided by the student though is very weird, since it implies that A has at most 2 distinct subsets, and thus only contain one element at most, which interprets a lot of context to such a small part of a sentence that it is a very unlikely way to write a question. In my opinion the interpretation more speaks about the student not having looked at set theory exercises before, and thus not knowing how things should be interpreted.

One way to formulate it though to avoid this interpretation is to use the word "any" instead:

> For any subsets $C,D\subseteq A$, ...

Thuogh this way of writing it probably also has some chance of missinterpretation.

Comment: The interpretation by the student is not weird, it is _wrong_. There's nothing ambiguous about what the OP wrote. Of course there are multiple ways to interpret words. In this context only one interpretation is correct.

Comment: I think using the word *wrong* about an interpretation is a bit harsh. Any interpretation which is not what the author intended is in some sence wrong, though in more ambiguous cases we might not call students out for it. If the student has never seen mathematical/set-theory reasoning before, then doing intended interpretation is hard. Thus calling the students interpretation for weird or some other less harsh word Is proper I think.

Comment: I know you think that. You're wrong, sorry. Words in mathematics have _definitions_. Consider the sentence "Every integer $n>1$ is a product of primes". If we "interpret" "integer $n>1$" to mean "abelian group" and we "interpret" "product of primes" to mean "differentiable function" then the sentence says that every abelian group is a differentiable function. That's not a problem with the sentence - that interpretation is simply wrong. The student's interpretatioin of what the OP wrote is _wrong_ in exactly the same way.

Comment: Mathematical symbols have definitions, but the English language have ambiguities. If we write $\forall n(n>1 \rightarrow \ldots)$ then we are on the safe side, but each time we use the english language there is a chance (more or less in different cases) for missinterpretation. What is wrongly intepreted is allways from the eyes of the author. Though It seems like we just have to agree that we disagree.

Comment: Yes, English has ambiguities. And there are plenty of examples of ambiguously phrased mathematical statements. This simply is not one of them. "For every $B,C\subset A$" simply does not say that the only subsets of $A$ are $B$ and $C$. A student who thinks it says this, or maybe says this, needs to be informed that it simply doesn't. Calling ambiguous, or pupssyfooting trying to avoid the word "wrong", is not dong the student any favors.